# Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $H$ having a unique fixed point $y$, then $h(y) = y$ for all $h$ in $H$. Correct?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

**Prove**: Let $H$ be a group of permutations of the set $X$. Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $H$ having a unique fixed point $y$, i.e.
$\{ y \}$ = $\{x \in X : k(x) = x\ \forall k \in K\}$. Then $h(y) = y$ for all $h$ in $H$.

**Proof**: Let $H$ be a group of permutations of the set $X$. Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $H$ having a unique fixed point $y$. Therefore, $\forall k \in K, \forall h \in H, hkh^{-1} \in K$. Since $y$ is the unique fixed point for all $k$ in $K$, and $K$ is normal, $hkh^{-1}$ fixes $y$. Then, $hkh^{-1}(y) = y$, which implies $k(h^{-1}(y)) = h^{-1}(y)$. Then $k$ fixes $h^{-1}(y)$. Since $y$ is a unique fixed point in $X$, $h^{-1}(y) = y$. Therefore, $h(h^{-1}(y)) = h(y)$, and hence $h(y) = y$ for all $h$ in $H$.

So this was my attempt at the proof. Sorry for the repetitive nature of the proof relative to the problem statement, I always start with what I am given. I assumed because normality was given, the property needed utilized and that is where I began my train of thought. However, after convincing myself this proof was valid a peer said this was incorrect. I can not see why. Anyone have a clue to the flaw in logic? Thank you.

Comment: Ask that peer what his reasons are to tell you the proof is wrong...

Comment: Their justification was they proved it similarly and was told it was wrong.

Comment: I really didn't understand that: so your peers proved the claim...and then they told you your proof was wrong, just like that? And you accepted that!?

Comment: Peer said they proved the claim in a similar manner but someone else told them it was incorrect. Therfore, they told me my proof is incorrect. I did not accept it but rather acknowledge the possibility my proof was not 100% valid and came here for input. I am convinced my proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof uses a stronger assumption, namely, that
$$\forall k\in K\ :\  \{y\}=\{x\in X: k(x)=x\}\,.$$
(By the way, it is so strong that $|X|=1$ is implied, as the identity has to be in $K$, and every point is a fixed point for that.)

But basically the same argument goes through, as $h(y)$ (or $h^{-1}(y)$ if you prefer) will be anyway fixed by each $k\in K$.

Comment: What I don't understand: If $S$ is the stabilizer group of $y$ then (assuming $H$  acts transitively on $X$) $X$ can be identified with $H/S$, the set of right cosets of $S$ in H (with the right multiplication as action). It is known that the stabilizers of other elements of $X$ are conjugates of $S$. Now saying  $K$ fixes $y$ is equivalent to say that $K \subseteq S$ so if K is normal then  K lies in all the conjugates of $S$, so $K$ fixes all the points of $X$.